# How to structure GraphQL data to include MDX parent directory name

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a simple Gatsby app that uses MDX files to generate pages (based on the starter app from the Gatsby tutorials).

I have a folder structure similar to this:

```
/checks
  /category1
    - example1.mdx
  /category2
    - example2.mdx
```

I want the data GraphQL returns to be structured similar, so I can grab the name of each category, for example something similar to:

```
{
  "checks": {
    "category1": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "title": "example 1",
            "slug": "exp1",
            "topic": "category1"
          }
        },
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "title": "example 2",
            "slug": "exp2",
            "topic": "category1"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "category2": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "title": "example 3",
            "slug": "exp3",
            "topic": "category2"
          }
        },
        {
          "frontmatter": {
            "title": "example 4",
            "slug": "exp4",
            "topic": "category2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to get anywhere near this result using the Gatsby graphQL editor - how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're sourcing your MDX files through `gatsby-source-filesytem`. For each file, a `File` node is created.

`gatsby-plugin-mdx` takes those `File` nodes and creates child `Mdx` nodes for them so that you can query `allMdx`/`mdx`.

You can use this parent-child relationship in both ways. Use a [GraphQL union / inline fragment](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types) to access the `parent`. You can figure out which parent is available like this:

```
query {
  allMdx {
    nodes {
      parent {
        __typename
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You should get back something like this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "allMdx": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "parent": {
            "__typename": "File"
          }
        },
     ]
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

Then you can query something like this:

```
{
  allMdx {
    nodes {
      parent {
        ... on File {
          name
          relativeDirectory
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```